# rxjs observable.pipe not firing in HttpTestingController

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine

I am using HttpTestingController to mock http requests/response. If I use the code below:

```js
httpClient.get('/my/url/', { observe: "response" }).pipe(

switchMap(response => {
                   ... 
                   
                   processing
                   
                   ...
                })
            );
```

it does not trigger HttpTestingController to flush with a response. If I use the code below, it does trigger HttpTestingController to flush a request. Any idea why is this not working? I tested both scenarios in the app itself and both methods send http requests.

```js
httpClient.get('/my/url/', { observe: "response" }).subscribe(response => {
                       ... 
                       
                       processing
                       
                       ...
                    })
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

A rxjs `Observable` do not consume without at least one subscriber

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a `switchMap` inside of a `subscribe`.

In your test, for the first scenario, make sure you are `subscribing` to the method and then flush, then it should work.

Comment: the switchMap was a typo while pasting and modifying my code. The first snippet, it does send the request in the app so it is firing the request but not in Jasmine.

Comment: Yes because you are subscribing to it from somewhere else. In `Jasmine`, in the `it` block, make sure you subscribe to it as well.